# Communication between two threads created by a main thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

So I have to create three Teller threads, and 100 Client threads.

Each thread must follow a sequence of actions, printing a record of each action.

the Teller threads must: notify the client that its available, accept id and transaction from a client, respond to client, .. and so on

the client has a similar set of actions: wait in line, when signaled select a free teller, etc

What I don't understand is, how do I get these threads to communicate?

So I make three Teller threads from the main method, 100 client threads, how exactly do I connect a client thread to a teller thread? Obviously when the three teller threads open, they can only take 3 clients, so 97 other client threads will be waiting. How do I stop the Client's run() method so the threads are still alive while waiting for an open Teller?

Comment: You can use a BlockingQueue to exchange messages. The official API doc is detailed.

Comment: As @amanin said, a simple way is to implement a `isFree()` function on the `Teller.class`

Comment: How would I go about exchanging data between client and teller threads?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Count Down Latch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Basically it works like this:
Count down latch signal helps by making client wait if all tellers are busy at the moment and notifies client thread if signal's count reaches 0 ( which means it's my turn).

My suggestion is, create a count down latch signal with count equal to 1 for each client and store them in a data structure(I recommend a queue), so everytime a teller is done with a client just pop a count down latch signal from the queue, then decrease popped signal's count to 0, so the client with this signal gets notified.

I recommend a queue because after every pop it deletes the element, so there are no any data races ( thread's reading the same element at the same time, which makes a client be served by two threads ).

I hope this helps.

Comment: This help a bit, but how exactly do I exchange data between the client and teller threads?

Answer (score 0):

Exchanging data between classes is done via class methods.
Likewise, exchanging messages between `Thread`s is done via class methods.

If *everything* is local, ie you don't have to send anything over an online network, then you can try the following code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static class MessageSource {
    }

    public static class Message<S extends MessageSource> {
        private final S origin;

        public Message(final S origin) {
            this.origin = Objects.requireNonNull(origin);
        }

        public S getOrigin() {
            return origin;
        }
    }

    public static class ClientRequest extends Message<Client> {
        public ClientRequest(final Client origin) {
            super(origin);
        }
    }

    public static class TellerResponse extends Message<Teller> {
        public TellerResponse(final Teller origin) {
            super(origin);
        }
    }

    public static class Teller extends MessageSource implements Runnable {
        private final Queue<ClientRequest> sharedQueue;

        public Teller(final Queue<ClientRequest> sharedQueue) {
            this.sharedQueue = Objects.requireNonNull(sharedQueue);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final Random rand = new Random();
                while (true) {
                    final ClientRequest r;
                    synchronized (sharedQueue) {
                        while (sharedQueue.isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println("Teller " + hashCode() + " says queue is empty.");
                            sharedQueue.wait();
                        }
                        r = sharedQueue.poll();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Teller " + hashCode() + " currently seving request from Client " + r.getOrigin().hashCode() + "...");
                    Thread.sleep(250 + rand.nextInt(250)); //Delay a bit, to simulate serving the request and creating the response...
                    r.getOrigin().response(new TellerResponse(this)); //One could say that this simulates an RPC call :P
                }
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException ix) {
                System.err.println("Teller " + hashCode() + " stopped serving clients abruptly: " + ix);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Client extends MessageSource implements Runnable {
        private final Queue<ClientRequest> sharedQueue;
        private TellerResponse privateQueue; //Since responses will be received here, I call this a queue (although it's not, because we know we can serve only one response at a time).

        public Client(final Queue<ClientRequest> sharedQueue) {
            this.sharedQueue = Objects.requireNonNull(sharedQueue);
        }

        public synchronized void response(final TellerResponse r) {
            privateQueue = r;
            notifyAll(); //Could be notify(). No difference would it make in this specific case.
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //I'm just implementing random count of random-data requests...
            final Random rand = new Random();
            final int numberOfRequests = 5 + rand.nextInt(6);
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequests; ++i) {
                    final ClientRequest req = new ClientRequest(this);
                    synchronized (sharedQueue) {
                        sharedQueue.add(req);
                        sharedQueue.notifyAll(); //Could be notify(). No difference would it make in this specific case.
                    }
                    synchronized (this) {
                        while (privateQueue == null)
                            wait();
                        System.out.println("Client " + hashCode() + " can consume the " + privateQueue.getOrigin().hashCode() + " Teller's response...");
                        privateQueue = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException ix) {
                System.err.println("Client " + hashCode() + " stopped receiving responses abruptly: " + ix);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Queue<ClientRequest> requests = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            new Thread(new Client(requests)).start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            new Thread(new Teller(requests)).start();
    }
}
```

A single `ClientRequest` is answered by a `Teller` with a single `TellerResponse`.
Now you have to extend the classes `ClientRequest` and `TellerResponse` according to your needs (ie implement what data should be exchanged).

This implementation is a producer-consumer pattern where both the Tellers and the Clients are both producers and consumers.
This implementation uses a shared queue to exchange messages from clients to tellers.

There is no stopping condition for the tellers (which makes them wait indefinetly at the end of the clients' requests) which will make the program wait forever at the end of the clients' requests.
But this is expected since we have no terminating condition.

The clients will run creating from 5 up to 10 requests. The tellers will delay each response from 250 to 500ms. With 3 tellers and 100 clients, that makes us about from 42 up to 167 seconds runtime.

A more reallistic communication approach I guess would use `PipedInputStream`s and `PipedOutputStream`s to simulate traffic over blocking streams (such as network traffic).